# не могу решить проблему с отступами "expected an indented block after function definition on line..." после класса Main.window

Tags: python, отступы

Не могу решить проблему с отступом, все выглядит как положено, однако подсвечивается красный курсор после строки `class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):`

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.update_spinbox_value)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.image_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.image_label.setFixedSize(600, 400)
        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.image_label)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(625, 80, 0, 700)

        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.update_image)

    def update_spinbox_value(self, index):
        if index == 0:
            self.spinBox_2.setValue(0.8)  # Присвоение вероятности каждой засаде
        elif index == 1:
            self.spinBox_2.setValue(0.75)
        elif index == 2:
            self.spinBox_2.setValue(0.7)  
        elif index == 3:
            self.spinBox_2.setValue(0.65)
        elif index == 4:
            self.spinBox_2.setValue(0.6)
        elif index == 5:
            self.spinBox_2.setValue(0.55)  
        elif index == 6:
            self.spinBox_2.setValue(0.5)
```

Comment: def setupUi() пустая в классе Ui_Form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что функция `Ui_Form.setupUi` пустая.

Решить это можно либо добавлением нужного кода в функцию, либо добавить ключевое слово `pass` в функцию так:

```py
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        pass # эту строку я добавил
```